# ¿Como hacer un login a una base de datos en línea?

Tags: android, xamarin

tengo una base de datos en un servidor , para hacer consultas los usuarios deben hacer login, con su usuario y contraseña, al hacerlo ,les aparece una ventana con  el nombre de usuario y su nivel de permisos.

Todo funciona bien . Mi pregunta es , como puedo implementar el mismo sistema de login ,( que autentique usuario y contraseña) , haciendo una aplicación en Android, ya hice un ejemplo para conectarme a la base de datos y todo salió bien , de hecho no es algo difícil, lo que no he podido resolver es como hacer ese sistema de login y que lo valide a la base de datos que tengo, y me muestre un toast con el nombre de usuario que ha hecho login y su nivel de permisos.

Estoy usando visual studio 2017 con xamarin .

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando un servidor me imagino que tienes un servicio REST con el que los usuarios hacen log.

Implementar unas llamadas a un servidor lo puedes hacer con `Retrofit` http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Al tener que llamar al servidor, básicamente tienes que crear un método para enlazar tu app con el servidor.

Pongamos que tu ruta es /login

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("login")
LoginResponse<User> login(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);
```

Tendrás que crear una clase LoginResponse que recogerá lo que el servidor devuelva. Pongamos que mandas un mensaje de éxito y el token.

```
class LoginResponse {
  @SerializedName("message")
  private message;
  @SerializedName("token");
  private token;

  //getter y setter
}
```

Sólo tendrías que llamar al cliente de Retrofit (esto viene explicado en la web que te he puesto) y llamar a la función de la interface para que la app lame al servidor.